# Can I download to my laptop while playing on my pc?

Tags: steam

I want to download a huge online game onto my laptop, to do so, I can't seem to be online in steam on my pc. Is there a way to do that? Going forward, I can't leave both online on steam to get updates while I'm not playing on either?

Comment: I'm facing the same sitation at the moment - and, from what I can tell, you can't even login on two PCs at once.

Comment: You can if you play a game that does not require internet and then go in offline mode on the pc while you download on your laptop

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the game files from one computer to the other across your local network. If you use an Ethernet cable, this will probably be faster than downloading from steam.

Identify the game folder on your PC and then copy them over to the laptop, then verify the game files via the steam client on the laptop.

See (for instance): https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129

"Move" in the above link is another way of saying copy and delete. Just don't delete the files in the source folder.

Note that windows 7 has a command line tool called "robocopy" which can be set to mirror files (aka "sync folders"). With a little creativity, it can be set to mirror a game folder between computers, provided these folders do not have computer-specific config data stored within them.

Answer (score -1):

You may create another account in Steam. Then connect both with `Steam Family Sharing` and download it that way.
Once it's finished, you may login with your main account and see that that game is downloaded.